# Remove 00 from Byte Array in C# (Encoding to String)

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, byte

I use a `NFC-Reader` to read data. The data will be stores as `byte[] bytes_credentials`. Receiving data is working fine but now I want to encode the 16 byte Array to String. I use `string str = Encoding.Default.GetString(new_data);` for decoding the array. The string output is working fine if the byte Array is fully "booked up" (16 of 16 bytes used), for example: `This is an test!` -> `54 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 61 6e 20 74 65 73 74 21`. The problem i am facing is, that if the NFC-Array is not fully "booked up", the Array look like this: `This is!` -> `54 68 69 73 20 69 73 21 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`. The output in console looks like this: `This is!????????`.

How can I CHECK and REMOVE the empty bytes (00) from the Array. So that the Output looks like this: `This is!`.

Thank you for helping!!!
I have checked previous posts but no of them are working for me...

Comment: If you're programming in C#, why did you add the totally irrelevant C language tag? Despite the names being similar, they are two very different languages.

Comment: As it stands you could just do `yourBytes.Where(b => b != 0)` or possibly `yourBytes.Reverse().SkipWhile(b => b == 0).Reverse()` But it sounds like you are reading into a buffer, but not using the resulting number of bytes read to pass into `Encoding.GetString`. Please show your code so we can understand how to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to filter your array further:

```
using System.Text;

var bytes_credentials = new byte[]
{
    0x54,
    0x68,
    0x69,
    0x73,
    0x20,
    0x69,
    0x73,
    0x21,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
};

Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(
    bytes_credentials.Where(b => b != 0).ToArray()
));
```

To learn more about LINQ, take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/